# Problem with VSCode?

Tags: apt, updates, microsoft

When i run sudo apt update i got problem with VSCode:

```
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/source/Sources' as repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease' does not seem to provide it (sources.list entry misspelt?)
```

Why does VSCode have problems?